# How to click element using selenium web driver(Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click an element using selenium chromedriver by the Use of ID of an element to click.

I want to Click Year '2020" from the following webpage: 'https://www.satp.org/datasheet-terrorist-attack/major-incidents/Pakistan'

I tried with the below code.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriver_Path, options = options)
driver.get('https://www.satp.org/datasheet-terrorist-attack/major-incidents/Pakistan')

Id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvMajorIncident_ct123_lbtnYear" ### Id of an Element 2020
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)  ##Wait for 20 seconds
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, Id)))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
element.click()
time.sleep(10)
```

but unfortunately this gives an Error as below:

```
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, Id)))
  File "C:\Users\Pavan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Please anyone help me on this... Thanks;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if your imports were correct. Also, your code doesn't scroll to the bottom of the page. Use this.

```
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='driver path')
driver.get('https://www.satp.org/datasheet-terrorist-attack/major-incidents/Pakistan')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(3)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvMajorIncident_ctl23_lbtnYear"]')))
element.click()
```